# Rails form_tag inside .each loop, incorrect project id inside form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Routes
resources :users do
  get 'following' => 'users#following'
  resources :projects
end

Controller
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end
end

View
<% @user.projects.each do |project| %>
  <div class="hidden">
    <%= form_tag({:controller => "projects"}, :method => "put", :id => "form") do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :title, nil, class: "form-control" %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "project_id", project.id %>
      <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn-inline" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I need to pass project.id to my controller, the project params in the hidden_field_tag keeps saying that it's 1 for every project. If I do <%= project.id %> outside the form_tag, then it displays the correct project id, but inside the form_tag, it shows 1 for every project. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean that the hidden field renders with a value of 1 every time?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Bootstrap popover to show a form when a button is clicked. When the form appears, it renders project id 1, however if i just do a normal <%= text_field_tag :project, project.id %>, then the correct project id is in the input box.  I think I need to pass the project id from the button to the input box?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is more in that popover that you use than in your code, which I tested and works fine. I would suggest using something like Firebug to look at the generated HTML code on your page and see what value that has your hidden_field_tag.

Good luck!

Comment: You are right, I had the hidden field tag in the wrong spot.  It works now.  Thanks!